# JMenu: add(Action a) vs add(new JMenuItem(Action a)

Tags: java, swing

I constructed a JMenu and would now like to add menu items. So what I have is:

- JMenu jm
- Action act

Now, for adding a menu item triggering action act: Does it make a difference if I use

```
jm.add(act);
```

or

```
jm.add(new JMenuItem(act));
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation for [JMenu.add(Action)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JMenu.html#add%28javax.swing.Action%29), it will create a new menu item for you, so they are essentially the same. So it's ultimately a convenience method.

However, it also states:

> As of 1.3, this is no longer the
>   preferred method for adding Actions to
>   a container. Instead it is recommended
>   to configure a control with an action
>   using setAction, and then add that
>   control directly to the Container.

And if we look at the source code for JMenu (retrieved from [Google Code Search](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#K_itPObJgso/trunk/jdk5/main/src/javax/swing/JMenu.java&q=JMenu%5C.java%20%22as%20of%201.3%22)),  this is what the `add(Action)` method looks like:

```
public JMenuItem add(Action a) {
    JMenuItem mi = createActionComponent(a);
    mi.setAction(a);
    add(mi);
    return mi;
}
```

So no, there isn't a big difference. But I'd still follow the documentation's recommendation by manually making a control anyway.

Comment: Does anyone have information as to why the first option is no longer the preferred method? I tried to find explanations via Google but couldn't. Since it does internally what is suggested to be done explicitly, where is the advantage of increased verbosity in this case? (Sorry if the answer to this question is obvious to everyone else but me - I'm still a programming newbie, trying to learn.)

Comment: @Steps I frankly don't know -- increased verbosity tends to be a bad thing -- but if I had to guess, I'd say it's possibly for more control, and because it makes more sense to add to a jmenuitem to a jmenu, then to add some abstract action. If you want to go for the less verbose way, feel free. It's not deprecated, just not preferred.

Comment: @Steps [this bug report](http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do;jsessionid=e73a2a018ad4226aa201304c5a80b?bug_id=4626632) may help illuminate why they are not preferred